# Formatting SD card as FAT32 on Mac?

Tags: disk-utility, macos, disk-format, sd-card

Named brand micro SD with 8 gigs on it. Trying everything to format as FAT32, on a Mac running Sierra and I get this error:

```
/dev/disk2s1 does not appear to be a whole disk
```

When running this:

```
$ diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk2s1 1 MBRFormat "MS-DOS FAT32" UDOO 1024M
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: You need to post the commands you are trying to run. Also post output of `diskutil list /dev/disk2`

Comment: $ diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk2s1 1 MBRFormat "MS-DOS FAT32" UDOO 1024M ...is the command I was trying to run.

Comment: Are you using disk utility?

Answer (score 3):

`partitionDisk` wants the entire drive as its target, because it's about to erase all partitions & replace with your new parameters.

`/dev/disk2s1` is your existing 1st partition on that drive, `disk2` is what it's looking for. I'm not actually certain why `dev/disk2` wouldn't work, but it doesn't.
That would make your command
`$ diskutil partitionDisk disk2 1 MBRFormat "MS-DOS FAT32" UDOO 1024M`

You can also simplify the command if you like, as far as
`$ diskutil partitionDisk disk2 1 MBR fat32 UDOO 1024M`
& it will still work.

As pointed out in comments, the volume name only needs to be in quotes if there's a space. I'd missed that, my bad.

Ref: http://ss64.com/osx/diskutil.html